# Nested List Product

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to apply `Times` on the elements of a list such that:

```
{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19} => 
{{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19},{6,35,143,323},{210,46189},{9699690}}
```

I wrote this function :

```
listProduct[list_] := 
 Apply[Times, Partition[list, Ceiling[Length[list]/2]]]

Nest[listProduct, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, 1]
```

Using `Nest` at each level generate the desired element but I am having difficulties with combining the results. Also, I want to be able to use each element once computed.

Comment: For what it's worth your original version is faster than the answers provided.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard my original version is incomplete so I asked how to combine them at once and also how to have access to them once they're computed not at the end. No answer yet.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: "I want to be able to use each element once computed."  Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it is an iterative computation, as an example when 2*3 => 6 and then 6*35 => 210 I want have access (a simple Print here) to both 6 and 35 in the middle of computation not at the end and using [[]] over the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do :

```
listProduct2[list_] := Times @@@ Partition[list, 2, 2]

NestList[listProduct2, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, 3]
(* {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {6, 35, 143, 323}, {210, 46189}, {9699690}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to count how often you have to call the function, you can use `FixedPointList` which automatically stops when there is nothing more to multiply

```
FixedPointList[
 Times @@@ Partition[#, 2, 2] &, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}]
(*
{{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {6, 35, 143, 323}, {210, 46189}, 
 {9699690}, {}, {}}
*)
```

To get rid of the last two empty lists you can use `Drop[..,-2]`

Answer (score 0):

**Using `BlockMap`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
FixedPointList[BlockMap[Apply[Times], #, 2] &, list] // Most // Most
```

> {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {6, 35, 143, 323}, {210,    46189},
> {9699690}}

---

```
WolframLanguageData["BlockMap"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

> {10.2, DateObject[{2015, 7, 14}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.]}